# JDBC: Reading Native Select Query Result Set of Deep Level Table Hierarchy and Populating into Value Objects

Tags: sql, jdbc

I have below tables, where country can have multiple states, state can have multiple cities, city can have multiple areas, area can have multiple streets.

**Data Base Tables:**

```
Country { countryid, name, description }
State { stateid, name, description, countryid (FK) }
City { cityid, name, description, stateid (FK) }
Area { areaid, name, description, cityid (FK) }
Street { streetid, name, description, areaid (FK) }
```

**Java Value Objects to hold the values:**

```
CountryVO { countryId, name, description, List<StateVO> }
StateVO { stateId, name, description, List<CityVO> }
CityVO { cityId, name, description, List<AreaVO> }
AreaVO { areaId, name, description, List<StreetVO> }
StreetVO { streetId, name, description }
```

I want to fetch all the records with native select query and populate my value objects based on the query result set.

**Select Query**

```
select  country.id, country.name, country.description, 
    state.id, state.name, state.description,
    city.id, city.name, city.description,
    area.id, area.name, area.description,
    street.id, street.name, street.description,     
from Country country, State state, City city, Area area, Street street
where country.id = state.id
    and state.id = city.id
    and city.id = area.id
    and area.id = street.id
```

I will fetch result set with below code:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(<above_select_query>);

List<Object[]> stList = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();

for (Object[] objects : stList) {

  // Here I will populate all my VOs based on values found in result set
}
```

Notice that, here I may get result set with duplicate column values:

for example:

If a Country (country-1) has two states (state1, state2) and both states have two cities (state1-city1, state1-city2, state2-city1, state2-city2) and same for areas and streets.

```
Row1: country-1  |  state1   | state1-city1
Row2: country-1  |  state1   | state1-city2
Row3: country-1  |  state2   | state2-city1
Row4: country-1  |  state2   | state2-city2
```

While populating my value objects I have to manually verify if Country object is created for first row it should not be created for remaining rows and same for rest of the values.

Is there any better pattern to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do that is to use a `Map<ID, VO>` for each kind of object.

Each time you read a row, you get the ID of the country in the row, then look if this country is alrady in the map. If it is not, you create it from the rest of the row cells, and put it in the map.

Then you do the same for the state. And if the state is not in its map yet, you create it, add it to its country, and add it to its map. etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sounds good idea. Still looking for other approaches.